# Есть ли возможность подменить системный загрузчик на Linux?

Tags: linux

Предоставляет ли Linux возможность заменить загрузчик исполняемого файла? Можно ли вообще создать свой собственный формат файла и загрузчик под него?

Answer (score 3):

Да, модуль [binfmt_misc](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt) позволяет создавать свой собственный формат файла и осуществлять его загрузку. Таким образом, например, запускаются и исполняются файлы `Java`.